# USB flash drive recognized as "iPOD"

Tags: macos, usb

My USB flash drive is recognized as  "iPOD" but on Windows it works ok.

[image]

Can I remount this from Terminal? Does OS X has an option such as "select driver"?

I couldn't find much related information.

Answer (score 1):

It looks like the vendor has named this device "iPOD". If your Mac was genuinely detecting your USB flash drive as an iPod, it would appear in iTunes and would also have the correct capitalisation ("iPod"). The manufacturer is listed as "i-FlashDrive", so it's not unreasonable to think that they'd set the device name to "iPOD".

As long as the USB flash drive is appearing as a disk, the correct driver has been selected and there is nothing to worry about.

Comment: thanks ! at the moment this is not recognised as an storage device so I was wondering if I can select the driver to use as we do in Windows. I run `diskutil list` and is not listed.